# rendering error in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

First, I want to say that i am a newbie to learn android development. I have signed for udacity.com course Android for beginners. I am in lesson 2A where it says to create a new project in android studio with the name "Just Java"

After the project is created it tells me to change to 21 but in my android studio. it is showing like this...................

I have [attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYWDa.png) the picture of the error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please don't post your code or error messages as an image](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3933332), but instead copy/paste any relevant code or errors and [use Markdown's code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to download all the libraries from the `SDK Manager` which you plan on using. It seems that you only have the latest one, API 23. To do this, go to SDK Manager (2nd icon to the left of the **?** question mark which is the right-most icon in the toolbar). Just hover over the icon and it'll say SDK Manager.

Click on **Launch Standalone SDK Manager** and tick all the libraries that you want to download and install, in your case `Android 5.0 (API 21)` and just click Install button. This will download and install everything you need and then you can select API 21 from the drop-down.

Answer (score 0):

Use this `compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'` on your build.gradle (module).

CoordinatorLayout is part of design liabrary where you project not able to find it.